# Android DrawerLayout - Enable children to take focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is it possible for the Drawer not block the children from receiving touch events:

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- THE MENU -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="staic_menu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainDrawer">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- LEFT DRAWER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When the drawer is open, the button is simply ignored.. But when its closed, the button works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom drawer.

Differences from the default one:

1. Doesn't close automatically
2. Doesn't dim the screen when open
3. Doesn't intercept touches when clicked outside of the drawer

The following code has these disadavantages/limitations:

- Will work with drawer on the left side (because of the width checks)
- Will assume that the `DrawerLayout`'s 2nd child is the `ListView` (or some other drawer content).
- Not closable the default way (swipe), only with the back button. You can implement that yourself (will need to enable/disable lock mode manually at some point).

**UnobtrusiveDrawer.java:**

```
public class UnobtrusiveDrawer extends DrawerLayout {

    public UnobtrusiveDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UnobtrusiveDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UnobtrusiveDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        View drawer = getChildAt(1);
        Log.e("TAG", "Ev: " + ev.getRawX() + " " + drawer.getWidth());
        if (isDrawerOpen(drawer) && ev.getRawX() > drawer.getWidth()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Drawer open, and click outside");
            return false;
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Drawer closed or click on it");
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {}

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {}

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {}
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<com.example.myapplication.UnobtrusiveDrawer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</com.example.myapplication.UnobtrusiveDrawer>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.. this creates a new issue.. when I add drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() { .... my fragment now stays aligned to the left.. When there is no DrawerListener, the DrawerMenu pushes the frgment to the righ.. Any idea on how this can be solved? I would like the Drawer to push the content to the right of the screen like this: http://goo.gl/6ODPfN